# How to get users by specific ID's WordPress

Tags: users

How to get users by specific users ID's in WordPress.

```
$args = array(
    'number'    => -1,
    'fields'    => array( 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' )
);
$users = get_users( $args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of users by their IDs you simply need to add the `include` argument to your query;

```php
$args [
  'include' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Get users of these IDs.
  'fields'   => [ 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' ],
];

$users = get_users( $args );
```

You don't need to use the `number` argument as you're already limiting your result by the amount of IDs provided in `include`. [See this page for more info on the available arguments.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/)

You could also use the `WP_User_Query` class to retrieve them;

```php
$args [
  'include' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Get users of these IDs.
  'fields'   => [ 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' ],
];

$user_search = new WP_User_Query( $args );
 
$users = $user_search->get_results();
```

Comment: Working. Thanks